# How long will QueryPerformanceCounter() return the correct value for 32 bit machine (without overflows)?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Will QueryPerformanceCounter return the correct value for 32-bit computer that is up for more than month or even a couple of months or years?

Thanks

Comment: What does "correct" mean? You might as well ask "what's the resolution about a general RTC".

Comment: It returns `LARGE_INTEGER`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-large_integer-r1 If you look at that page, `QuadPart `is a 64-bit integer. So to answer your question: yes

Comment: It can be hard to realize how truly big a 64-bit number can be.  2^64 is 18446744073709551616.  If it's counting ticks at 1 GHz, that's 18446744073.  There are 86400 seconds in a day, so that's 213503 days, or 584 years.  So I don't think you need to worry about your counter rolling over any time soon. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit You're assuming the QPC return value is not taken from a hardware counter with a smaller range, and then extended to 64 bits. I feel that a complete answer to OP's question _must_ address whether the underlying hardware counters can roll over more frequently than a 64-bit value would imply.

Comment: @zwol Fair point.  And look!  Someone has addressed it in an answer. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit I wasn't expecting to be able to find any actual documentation when I wrote the comment.

Comment: @zwol Microsoft is remarkably tight-lipped about what the numbers returned by QueryPerformanceCounter actually mean, aren't they?  I guess they're trying to leave maximum room for different implementation strategies on different architectures.  But that quote you found is an impressively appropriate, definitive answer to the OP's question!  Well done.

Comment: @ste The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter) says that this is a high resolution clock with ticks smaller than 1us. If you need to know the precise number of ticks per second, call [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancefrequency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft guarantees that QueryPerformanceCounter will not roll over sooner than 100 years from boot: quoting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps#general-faq-about-qpc-and-tsc

> **How often does QPC roll over?**
>
> Not less than 100 years from the most recent system boot, and potentially longer based on the underlying hardware timer used. For most applications, rollover isn't a concern.

You cannot deduce this just from the fact that QueryPerformanceCounter produces a 64-bit value.  The hardware clock used to implement QPC *could* have a much smaller range, and Windows *could* just be zero-extending that clock to 64 bits.  This is particularly plausible on the older 32-bit systems you were asking about.  Only explicit documentation of the rollover interval should be relied on.